# Найти и заменить строку в подстроке по шаблону

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

есть список инпутов
нужно заменить часть значения атребута name, которая находится в квадратных скобках на значения счетчика i;

```js
$('input').each(function(i, input){
  var name = $(input).attr('name');
  console.log(name);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="namevrv[1]" type="text"><br>
<input name="nametesdt[2]" type="text"><br>
<input name="namerrr[45]" type="text"><br>
<input name="nameaaa[4]" type="text"><br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> есть список инпутов нужно заменить часть значения атребута name, которая находится в квадратных скобках на значения счетчика i;

Вот так например:

```js
$('input').each(function(i, input){
  var name = $(input).attr('name');
   $(input).attr('name', name.replace(/\[(\d+)\]/, '['+ i + ']' ));
   console.log($(input).attr('name'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="namevrv[1]" type="text"><br>
<input name="nametesdt[2]" type="text"><br>
<input name="namerrr[45]" type="text"><br>
<input name="nameaaa[4]" type="text"><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(input).attr('name','name['+i+']');
```

Comment: исправил вопрос